# Can we auto-comment on a close vote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was reading through some of the posts here on Meta and going through some queues.

There were a number of questions voted closed as a "Request for legal advice" but there was no comment made to the question.

Obviously, I could write a comment remarking on the same, but would it be useful, at least for that specific close option, to have a comment auto-added to the question stating that it was identified as a question requesting legal advice and simple options to correct?

Is something like this even possible?
Is it already available and I just don't know it?

Answer (score 1):

I presume there is no technical reason to not do so; but it is a property of SE, not Law SE; but this would be potentially useful for every SE site. This would be a good Meta question, but I bet it will get closed because someone somewhere already asked something like this.

I think it would also be more useful to have a complete list of VTC reasons, not just the first or most prevalent. So if 3 different reasons are selected by voters, you get 3 auto-comments. I do not see any hope for proposing remedies w.r.t. "asking legal advice", which is a very site-specific reason, but perhaps for the "community-specific reason" subset, a link to a standard "don't ask" page would be useful.

I also do not know if there is a special feature whereby a low-rep person asking the question can see their vote-populated "close" panel.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe we could have language that we standardize / agree upon for this. I would be fine with making a comment, I just feel odd typing roughly the same thing repeatedly and trying to figure out how I should word it. I could see a benefit to have a prepared comment somewhere that I can paste, with a link to the don't ask page and/or if we have anything explaining what "legal advice" is and how to rephrase, which can be done very simply usually.